# How(why) compilation improves performance

Tags: performance, compilation

I'm searching to improve our magento project and I found some postings to suggest reasons.

one of repetitive reasons is to enable compilation.

And I found that my project is unable for compilation.

But I want to know how compilation improves performance and why.

I believe there is a clear reason not to enable compilation.

Answer (score 2):

The Compilation feature of Magento will allow you to compile all files of a Magento installation in order to create a single include path to increase performance.

The performance increase is between `25%-50%` on page loads. In order to use this tool, the directory `includes` and the file `includes/config.php` must both be writable.

You can temporary disable it in Go admin side  » `System » Tools » Compilation` by clicking the Disable button and the Compiler include path will be disabled. Then, after the extension installation run the compilation process again.

**IMPORTANT:**

Please, make sure that you use the `Run Compilation Process` function after the installation, not the `Enable Compilation` - otherwise, you are likely to get backend fatal errors.

Before you make any changes to your Magento installation you should always disable compilation.
Once the changes are made, run the compilation process, and then enable it.

[More Details](http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path)

Comment: What does 'installation' of the sentence : "you use the Run Compilation Process function after the installation" mean?

Comment: Ofcourse, it is installed , i can see the ui, isn't it?

Comment: If  compilation enable and installation new module or extension then it is not working

Comment: Magento module or extension installation you should always disable compilation

Comment: Make sure that you use the Run Compilation Process function after the new module or extension installation.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will compile all of its files to create a single include path, which will help us reduce page load time by up to 50%. To run this compilation process, go to System > Tools > Compilation. In the top-right hand corner, you’ll see the Run Compilation Process button. Click on that and you’re done.

```
Log into your Magento Admin Backend
Go to System ->> Tools ->> Compilation

Now, Click on "Run Compilation Process" to compile the Magento Installation Files
```

Once you run the compiler, it may take a while for Magento to compile all of its installation files. Once the compilation has been completed you will be notified and the "Compiler Status" and "Compilation State" will update accordingly.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: What does a single include path mean and thats role?

Comment: it will check the all files for error at once. and also improve the performance by getting all files.